# How to make sure a string contains more then automatically inputed defaults?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an input form to create a customField name, when the page loads the textbox is automatically filled with "cst_".

I preset this value in my class:

```
class customField{

    // DEFINE PROPERTIES
    public $id = 0;
    public $groupId;
    public $name = 'cst_';
    public $displayName;
    public $type;
    public $defaultValue;
    public $required;
    public $orderCount;
    ...
```

When I go to save the fields on my page, I check to make sure that the user has imputed more values than just leaving the "cst_"

I do this by simply:

```
// CHECK FOR ONLY "cst_"
if(strlen($customField->name > 4)){

    // SAVE
    $customField->save();

}else{ noticeSet(1,'PLEASE ADD NAME');noticeSet(1,strlen($customField->name));}
```

in my textbox I added `cst_water hardness` however I get the error

> PLEASE ADD NAME
>
> 18

I don't understand how it is failing at that `if` statement

I've added a `noticeSet` before the `if` statement and it shows `18`.

Is there any better way to see if a user has added more than just "cst_"?

Comment: You gave up and nothing helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parentheses out of place so you end up with `($customField->name > 4)` which results in `false`.  So the expression ends up  `if(strlen(false))` which is obviously no good.  Fix it with:

```
if(strlen($customField->name) > 4){
```

If `cst_` must be present, then maybe:

```
if(strpos($customField->name, 'cst_') === 0 && strlen($customField->name) > 4){
```

Or shorter but probably slower:

```
if(preg_match('/cst_.+/', $customField->name)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `$customField->name` contain the name? Is that checked? If so, i can see a problem in your code. You use:

```
if(strlen($customField->name > 4)){ ...
```

It should be:

```
if(strlen($customField->name) > 4){ ...
```

Anyway, this just will check that the name length is greater than 4. It won't check if it is "cst_".

Instead, you should be doing something like:

```
if (isset($customField->name) && $customField->name != "cst_") {
  //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement should read

```
if(strlen($customField->name) > 4){
```

(note the moved bracket)

Ideally, though, you want

```
if ($customField->name != "cst_") {
```